# Tilemill Index problem

Tags: tilemill

I have created my own customized tile. Now I am facing some problem with its indexing or naming convention. I am giving an clear example. I have taken an area where 6 tiles were created. In Google Maps or OSM in the same extent its giving 6 tiles and the same tiles. So there is no referencing or projection problem. Even the X or the folder name is also matching. I am getting trouble with the Y column or Image name. Its not matching. I have taken a close look at it. Interestingly I found in Google or OSM the Y column is incrementing from top to bottom where as tilemill created tiles number those incrementing from bottom to top. That is why the naming of tiles are not matching. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a double of an issue asked in our support queue. I [answered it here](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/2581-tilemill-tile-index-problem).